# mvn dependency:tree doesn't really show all dependencies

Tags: java, maven, tree

I ran into an issue compile a jar with many dependencies, in particular overlapping versions of `snakeyaml` (we need 1.11, some dependency was pulling in 1.9).  We ran `mvn dependency:tree` but we did not see the offending secondary version in any of the output.  On further inspection, is was `jruby-complete` that was then pulling in `snakeyaml`.  Why didn't `mvn dependency:tree` show us this level of drill down:

```
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-it:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-shell:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-prefix-tree:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop-compat:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.apache.hbase:hbase-hadoop2-compat:jar:0.98.6-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.jruby:jruby-complete:jar:1.6.8:compile
                              >>>>>>> WHY ARE THERE NO DEPENDENCIES HERE? >>>>>>>>>
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.cloudera.htrace:htrace-core:jar:2.04:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.5.0-cdh5.2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

Why wasn't [the dependencies of jruby-complete](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jruby%7Cjruby-complete%7C1.6.8%7Cjar) listed in the tree?  Does `mvn dependency:tree` only gfo to a certain depth?  What are the rules here?  If `mvn dependency:tree` had simply shown us its `snakeyaml` dependency we could have saved a couple hours of complex debugging.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The lower version of the dependency was not displayed with verbose flag either.

Answer (score 18):

I believe [this forum topic](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/dependency-tree-depth-td114532.html) would answer your question. The dependency tree mojo prunes lower level dependencies if the dependency is already present higher in the tree. That means that all of jruby-complete's dependencies (if it has any) are listed at a shallower depth in the tree. You can use the [verbose flag](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#verbose) (`-Dverbose`) to show the ommitted dependencies.

Comment: So in this case, that would imply that the versions of the dependencies are not taken into account for the deduplication.  Is that your understanding as well?

Comment: That's probably the case. It's a bit hard to say which dependency is used because you could have the same dependency at the same depth in the tree, and at that point I couldn't say which would be used. I've always relied on Maven's M2E visualizations of the dependency hierarchy because it will show you the entire tree and omissions. You can see all the implicit dependencies as a list, click any one of them and it'll show you all the dependencies that depend on it, and the omissions. Works really well for me.

Comment: So how to see a used dependency I mean them which finally will be  in a fat jar

Comment: As it seems, `-Dverbose` does not work together with `-DoutputType=dot`. Come on Maven, all I wanted was a graphical representation of my dependencies...

Comment: Verbose not supported since maven-dependency-plugin 3.0

Comment: Verbose supported *again* in `3.3`

Comment: any source to confirm when this change was made? the tree output used to show all the dependencies whether a dependency will finally be effectively pulled in or not based on the precedence rules